# Mobile site going slightly outside the device screen width

Tags: css, width, bootstrap-5, column-width

I made this single [web page](https://gardendontcare.ca/compost%20hotline/composthotline.html) and when I view it my mobile device, and I thumb to the left, the width of the website shifts over slightly, like the left and right edges are not completely contained within the device screen. It doesn't shift around on the DuckDuckGo browser, but it does on Safari. Is anyone aware of how to correct this?

I've used Bootstrap Grid and tried to set the correct element width specifications with CSS.

Comment: This will be an overflow issue caused by the bounds of the spinning image. This is why you are able to scroll left / right, not only on mobile but on desktop as well. Tested on Chrome, Edge, Firefox and IE desktop browsers. This rotating overflow causes your horizontal scroll bar to rhythmically change in width.

Comment: I am also getting a horizontal scroll bar on large screens and it keeps changing size. Interestingly, the size changes are in time and in line with the scrolling marquee that you have at the foot of the page. You may need to go through the page and check the overflows as recommended above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's about the width of you div with the ID "spinningDial".
She's to big on small device.

Remove it for a test. Then the page width will be perfect on mobile device.
Or you can juste try to change the width of this div for a test (100px for example).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everyone. I changed the width of the spinning image and everything seems to be working. I had also forgotten that the corners of the transparent div extend further than the circle... whoops.